# ffmpeg Cg shader ITU 709 YCbYg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, shader, libav, cg

I have a viewer (mrViewer at sourceforge) that displays movie files by feeding YCbCr images and merging them later in a shader.  Currently I am trying to track a color issue in my viewer, not displaying DNxHD movies properly.  The EXR file is to be seen in RGB, not scene linear.  The movie was created from that EXR file in Nuke (a comp program).  All movie files are converted from EXR image without color space conversion in NUKE 11.  All movie files are encoded with video color range.

[Color_Profile_nuke11.exr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AhCuaYwQhWfmVK81ScYi0ZQlmwwRh1z1/view?usp=sharing)

[Color_Profile_nuke11_DNxHD_mov64_444.mov](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYYvjDh7k1K9Sv9ExRH57TtOPgwxjwjD/view?usp=sharing)

[Color_Profile_nuke11_DNxHD_mov64_422.mov](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFXaLOD6q-z54M1TxpweEnl7lW4-Xh1G/view?usp=sharing)

In the shader, I do (simplified Cg code):

```
  half3 pre;

  pre.r = tex2D(YImage, tc).r;  // Y
  pre.g = tex2D(UImage, tc).r;  // U
  pre.b = tex2D(VImage, tc).r;  // V

  half3 c;

  if ( coeffs )
  {
      pre += Koff;

      c.r = dot(Kr, pre);
      c.g = dot(Kg, pre);
      c.b = dot(Kb, pre);
  }
  else
  {

      half3 yuv;

      yuv.r = 1.1643 * ( pre.r - 0.0625 );
      yuv.g = pre.g - 0.5;
      yuv.b = pre.b - 0.5;

      c.r = yuv.r + 1.5958 * yuv.b;
      c.g = yuv.r - 0.39173 * yuv.g - 0.81290 * yuv.b;
      c.b = yuv.r + 2.017 * yuv.g;
  }

  Out output;
  output.pixel = c;
  return output;



// Send coeffs to shader shader (C++ code)
{
_shader->setUniform( "coeffs", 1 );
// HDTV  YCbCr coefficients
_shader->setUniform( "Koff", 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
_shader->setUniform( "Kr", 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.28033f );
_shader->setUniform( "Kg", 1.0f, -0.21482f, -0.38059f );
_shader->setUniform( "Kb", 1.0f, 2.12798f, 0.0f );
}
```

Now, my problem is that the ITU 709 (the one with the `dot()` calls) path seems to not be behaving properly.  It creates a washed out image.  I am wondering if this has to do with full `jpeg` and full `mpeg` not having taken into account or whether my coefficients are wrong.

If I set the color matrix to ITU709 in my C++ code with the ffmpeg library and let its swscale do the conversion, I get good color correspondence in the image if I select the (default) 601 path in the shader.

Comment: This is just an FYI, but I think you want to subtract (128.0/255.0) from g and b instead of 0.5. I have been attempting to solve a problem like this with BT.709 except with gamma adjustment, see this SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/53911662/763355

Comment: Your shader is not doing anything to to remove the gamma correction which would turn the non-linear gamma corrected values into linear values which shaders write to outputs. You will need to find out what gamma was used to encode the originals and then use the inverse of that to decode. Working Metal code for that kind of approach related to BT.709 can be found linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment